# How to show the repeating items of a database only once?

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a table with multiple rows which stores all the loan amount paid by a member.

This is how the current data comes

```
> =======================                                                                                                                           
> col1  | col2  | col3                                      
> A     | 100   |somedate  |                                            
> A     | 200   |somedate  |                                            
> A     | 300   |somedate  |                                            
> A     | 200   |somedate  |                                            
> B     | 100   |somedate  |                                            
> B     | 17    |somedate  |                                            
> B     | 54    |somedate  |                                            
> B     | 100   |somedate  |                                            
> B     | 100   |somedate  |
```

I want to have

```
> =======================                                                            
> col1  | col2  | col3                                              
> A     | 100   |somedate  |                                            
>       | 200   |somedate  |                                                            
>       | 300   |somedate  |                                                            
>       | 200   |somedate  |                                                             
> B     | 100   |somedate  |                                                      
>       | 17    |somedate  |                                                           
>       | 54    |somedate  |                                                            
>       | 100   |somedate  |                                                            
>       | 100   |somedate  |
```

Is it even possible?

Comment: You'll probably have to process the data (and create a new data object) which will be shown in the list (or whatever you need). So if you have an object containing all data, you will get them all, and put it in a different object which will look like the one you need !

Comment: Can you please provide the query which you are using to get data from sqlite?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your question is about how to store the data than the answer is: No it is not possible. the reason for this is that you need to identify to which row the data belongs.

For example: You want to query all 'B's with a loan amount of 100. The query would look like: `select col1, col2, col3 from mytable where col2 = 100 and col1 = 'B'`

On the incoming data structure your result would be three rows. On your desired structure it would be one row.

When it comes to presenting the data on a screen than it would be different, because you would work with the incoming data structure and only show the value of col1 when it is changing.

Comment: I don't need to store the data. It is just to be displayed on a screen.

Comment: So then the solution would be the check if the value of col1 changed as I mentioned in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

welcome aboard.

Since you only want to show the data, probably a code in each row: "if the current col1 is the same with the col1 before, don't show it" would be sufficient.

But if you want to use the data correctly, i would suggest a more database driven answer, where all the data of the same col come in a cell, and then you treat them as array (sepparating them with comma):

```
SELECT col1, GROUP_CONCAT(col2), GROUP_CONCAT(col3)
FROM stack_54178316
GROUP BY col1


| col1 | GROUP_CONCAT(col2) | GROUP_CONCAT(col3)                           |
| ---- | ------------------ | -------------------------------------------- |
| A    | 100,200,300,200    | somedate,somedate,somedate,somedate          |
| B    | 100,17,57,100,100  | somedate,somedate,somedate,somedate,somedate |
```

You can see the result here (just press PLAY):

https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/rnL91RcmS6QEE9eULwb4Uu/0